# Can Path of Exile be modified in terms of appearance?

Tags: path-of-exile

In my case, I want to replace the current models and textures for only armor items, so that I could make my character look cooler. *Note that I am aware that appearance mods for online games (if allowed) would be displayed only for people who installs this kind of thing.*

Thing is, I've been searching and all I found are appareantly web docs displaying "mods" (I believe those are more like stats tables), and not the actual type of mod I am looking for (texture/model replacements to inject).

Does the game allow to replace models and textures?

Comment: I recently found [a tutorial about editing textures](http://www.ownedcore.com/forums/mmo/path-of-exile/398988-tutorial-path-of-exile-editing-textures.html), yet I am not sure if this is still working as of today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it is technically possible to do what you are asking, it is worth mentioning that doing so violates the game's [Terms of Use](https://www.pathofexile.com/legal/terms-of-use-and-privacy-policy) and could result in banning:

> 6. Restrictions: Under no circumstances, without the prior written approval of Grinding Gear Games, may you:
>
> ...
>
> (b) Modify or adapt (including through third parties and third party
>   tools) the game client or its data, other than in the normal course of
>   POE gameplay as permitted in accordance with the Licence.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but only to a limited degree.

Among the microtransactions (MTX) available in the in-game shop are a variety of item effects and skins which you can apply to your items and skills. These modifications will be visible to all players who see you in game.